# Nativescript Bluetooth searching

Tags: bluetooth, nativescript

Im trying to search for Bluetooth devices with this plugin:

https://github.com/nativescript-community/ble

And evertimy I try to search for devices with this code:

```
doStartScanning(){
        {
            this.isLoading = true;
            // reset the array
            this.observablePeripheralArray.splice(0, this.observablePeripheralArray.length);
            this.bluetooth.startScanning(
              {
                filters: [{serviceUUID:'180d'}],   // pass an empty array to scan for all services
                seconds: 4,         // passing in seconds makes the plugin stop scanning after <seconds> seconds
                onDiscovered: function (peripheral) {
                  this.observablePeripheralArray.push(fromObject(peripheral));
                }
              }
            ).then(function() {
              this.isLoading = false;
            },
            function (err) {
                this.isLoading = false;
              alert({
                title: "Whoops!",
                message: err,
                okButtonText: "OK, got it"
              });
            });
          };
    }
```

I get this Error:

```
JS: Unhandled Promise rejection: Permission denied ; Zone: <root> ; Task: null ; Value: Permission denied undefined
```

Bluetooth is enabled and the permission granted from the Phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was a permissions error. Paste this in your android manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```